# Generate view without controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-controller

In my ASP.NET MVC project I have a controller that one action just result view. This Action does not get any argument and just return a CSHTML page. This page could not be partial.

Does anybody know a better way to generate view -  I mean can I generate view without controller action?

//Edit - sample codes

Right now in my UserPanelController i have an action ChangeSettings

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeSettings()
{
    return View("Configuration");
}
```

So if i want to get a configuration View i have to do request to controller from for example navigation:

```
<nav>
     <div class="nav-wrapper">
       <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
       <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("ChangeSettings","UserPanel")">Konrad</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Can i get a ConfigurationView without my controller action?

Comment: What do you mean by *"generate view without controller action"*?

Comment: Can you give your sample code, and please also clarify your question? The first sentence, ending "that one action just result view" is not English and it's impossible to guess what it means.

Comment: more information in main post - sorry for no samples

Comment: If you need the view to be dynamically rendered, it must flow through an MVC action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm a bit too late but what you are probably looking for is this:

```
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialViewName"); }
```

Notice that you can use a model in your view as well, by passing it directly from the view that is calling the partial one.

Answer (score 1):

You can render a view yourself by calling the following method

```
 private static string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This will give you html string containing your rendered view. I've used this before to render HTML for emails where the email content changed from user to user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if that email template has no controller?

Answer (score 0):

If it is static content, you can add an `.html` file inside your project. The web server will serve it.

To make sure the MVC routing will not interfer you can add something like this to your routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
```

Comment: but in static html file i cannot get information for example about current user name

Comment: No, exactly. The approach I described can be used only for static content. Otherwise you must create an action in a controller.